# Find the range of $a$ such that the result of the integration converges

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

Find the range of $a$ such that the result of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{a-1}{2}|x|^{-a}x^{2}d{x}$ converges

if $a$ > 1 and  $|X| \geq\ 1$.

My solution is for any $a > 3$ the integral converges.

I want to verify whether:
my change of variable (and the limit of integration) and result a > 3 is correct?

My try:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{a-1}{2}|x|^{-a}x^{2}d{x} = \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{a-1}{2}|x|^{-a}x^{2}d{x} + 
\int_{-\infty}^{-1} \frac{a-1}{2}|x|^{-a}x^{2}d{x}$$
$$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{a-1}{2}|x|^{-a}x^{2}d{x} = \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{a-1}{2}x^{-a}x^{2}d{x} \tag1$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{-1} \frac{a-1}{2}|x|^{-a}x^{2}d{x} = \int_{\infty}^{1} \frac{a-1}{2}z^{-a}z^{2}(-1)d{z} \tag2$$

Then just usual integration computation results in a term $x^{3-a}$ from (1) and similarly $z^{3-a}$ from (2)

However, these two terms do not cancel each other out with the -1 in (2), so $a$ needs to be greater than 3 for the result to converge

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150372/discussion-on-question-by-tjt-find-the-range-of-a-such-that-the-result-of-the); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First notice that $f(x)=|x|^{-a}x^2$ is an even function:
$$f(-x)=|-x|^{-a}(-x)^2=|x|^{-a}x^2=f(x)$$
and hence we can focus on the positive branch, as
\begin{align}
\int_{|x|>1}\frac{a-1}{2}|x|^{-a}x^2\,\mathrm{d}x&=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{a-1}{2}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x+\underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{-1}\frac{a-1}{2}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}_{\text{use subs. }u=-x}\\
&=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{a-1}{2}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x-\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{a-1}{2}f(-u)\,\cdot-\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{a-1}{2}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{a-1}{2}f(u)\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=2\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{a-1}{2}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
\end{align}

And in the positive branch $|x|=x$, so we can rewrite
$$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{a-1}{2}|x|^{-a}x^2\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{a-1}{2}\int_1^{\infty}x^{-a}x^2\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{a-1}{2}\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{a-2}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

For this last integral to converge, we know that we need $a-2>1\,\Rightarrow a>3$.

---

Attending to another issue in the comments: when writing an integral over the real line $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ and then impose the restriction $|x|>1$ is indeed confusing: this notation  explicitly requires you to consider all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Actually, if we consider the whole real line, the integral diverges for $a>3$ because you also include the interval $x\in[0,1]$, and $\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=\infty$.

As the restriction defines the integration interval, you should have started from an indefinite integral $\int g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ subject to $|x|>1$, which is exactly
$$\int_{|x|>1}g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{\infty}^{-1}g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_{1}^{\infty}g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$